# Finding a class of element and select a multiple class

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I don't sure, I calling right.. But I give you a demo

**HTML :**

```
<div class="demo one"></div>
<div class="demo two"></div>
```

If I have set variable like

`var element = $(".demo");`

then .. how can I select select a element with class `.one` ? like...

`element.withclass('.one')`

PS : I know I can just call `$(".demo.one")`

**Testing :** http://jsfiddle.net/UH6pj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to filter out the elements having classes `demo` and `one`

```
 elements = $('.demo').filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('one');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this using [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var element = $(".demo");
element.filter(".one");
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VbqNL/)